# How to work with lists in JPA Specifications

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, join, specifications

I've been trying to wrap my head around working with JPA Specifications but I cannot figure out how to convert this query:

```
select employees.* from employees
left join qualification_assignments on employees.qualification_profile_id =qualification_assignments.qualificationProfile_id
where qualification_id in <some list of strings>
```

I've been able to convert simple queries that only contain trivial predicates. However, there does not seem to be any documentation for more advanced use cases. I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

My attempts look like this which result in various exceptions:

```
Join<Employee, QualificationProfile> assignmentJoin = root.join("qualificationProfile");

return criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.in(assignmentJoin.get("qualificationAssignments"))
           .in(searchCriteria.getQualificationIds())).getGroupRestriction();
```

The following would make the most sense for me but the join does not work.

```
Join<Employee, QualificationAssignment> assignmentJoin = root.join("qualificationProfile");

return criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.in(assignmentJoin.get("qualificationId"))
           .in(searchCriteria.getQualificationIds())).getGroupRestriction();
```

The data model looks like this:

[image]

Comment: We prefer QueryDsl. Whit that tool you can fluently and simpler write queries.

Comment: You can set <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> in persistence.xml, then you see what is the query. Please share that and your wish sql.

Comment: @LászlóTóth I can't give you the output because I am not able to write a query that does not result in an exception. My wish sql is provided in the question. I just need a representation in the JPA Specification API

Comment: I thought, send me the logged pure sql statement, what the jpa generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/criteria-api-left-join-on-condition.html

Perhaps it helps. You can generate Meta class-es like Employee_.

```
Root<Employee> employee = query.from(Employee.class);
ListJoin<Employee, QualificationProfile> profiles = employee.join(Employee_.qualificationProfile, JoinType.LEFT);
profiles.on(criteriaBuilder.in(profiles.get(QualificationProfile_.qualificationAssignments), searchCriteria.getQualificationIds()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help from Lazlo Toth I got on the right track. Thank you so much.

The final specification looks like this:

```
Join<Employee, QualificationAssignment> profiles = root
                .join("qualificationProfile", JoinType.LEFT)
                .join("qualificationAssignments");
        
profiles.on(profiles.get("qualification").get("id")
                .in(new HashSet<>(searchCriteria.getQualificationIds())));

return profiles.isNotNull();
```

I'll take a closer look at the meta classes now that I have a functioning solution. I found https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/criteria-api-in-predicate.html to be very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome. A little bit better if you work with meta classes and not strings. If an table's column changed you have to search all strings. If you work with metadata then this bug come for building.